# How to loop a list of maps from json api dart/flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I have create a class model  to receive json data from API

```
class Competition {
  int id;
  String name;
  String code;
  String type;
  String emblem;
  Competition({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.code,
    required this.type,
    required this.emblem,
  });

  factory Competition.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Competition(
      id: data["matches"][0]["competition"]['id'],
      name: data["matches"][0]["competition"]['name'],
      code: data["matches"][0]["competition"]['code'],
      type: data["matches"][0]["competition"]['type'],
      emblem: data["matches"][0]["competition"]['emblem'],
    );
  }
}
```

the code work properly, every time index [0] change the coming data change for the next competition details

i want to make this index change automatically for fetching all data at one time, this index represent list data["matches"].length

My Api service look like

```
class ServiceApi {
      Future<Competition > getmatches() async {
        http.Response response = await http.get(
            Uri.parse('_url'),
            headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '_key'});
    String body = response.body;
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(body);
    Competition compitition = Competition.fromJson(data);
    int numberOfCompetition = data["matches"].length;
     return matches;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map it like this

```dart
List<Competition> compititionList = data['matches'].map((item) => Competition.fromJson(item));
print(compittionList[0].name);
```

Btw theres a typo(spelling mistake) in competition (just incase you want to fix it)

And thr model should be

```dart
class Competition {
  int id;
  String name;
  String code;
  String type;
  String emblem;
  Competition({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.code,
    required this.type,
    required this.emblem,
  });

  factory Competition.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Competition(
      id: data["competition"]['id'],
      name: data["competition"]['name'],
      code: data["competition"]['code'],
      type: data["competition"]['type'],
      emblem: data["competition"]['emblem'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work 
I got error :
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

Comment: i got the solution with myself there no help on this website